# (C++) How to pass a local variable from main to another function's body if the value is already inputed by user in main?

Tags: c++

The only way I was able to solve this is by creating global variables like `float x, y;` and then using those throughout the program. I am very new to programming as it's obvious, but I've heard that is usually a bad practice to create global variables.

My guess is that the problem occurs in the `void completeOperation(int z){}` function as error messages basically state that both the variable x and y haven't been declared. When I declare them in that scope, it asks me to give them a value while I need a user to input the said value in main.

How can I make this work? Forgive me for having to put the whole code up. It's tiny.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;         
void createMenu();
void completeOperation(int z);
float add(float x, float y);
float subtract(float x, float y);
float multiply(float x, float y);
float divide(float x, float y);
float greaterNumber(float x, float y);
float lesserNumber(float x, float y);

int main()
{
    float x, y;

    cout << "Enter the first real number value." << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the second real number value." << endl;
    cin >> y;

    createMenu();
    int z;
    cin >> z;

    completeOperation(z);

    system("pause");
}

void createMenu()
{
    cout << "\nChoose a desired arithmetic operation by entering a number from 1 to 6. \n\n";
    cout << "1.) Addition \n2.) Subtraction \n3.) Multiplication \n4.) Division \n5.) Bigger number \n6.) Smaller number" << endl;
}

void completeOperation(int z)
{
    switch (z)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "\nAddition: " << add(x, y) << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "\nSubtraction: " << subtract(x, y) << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "\nMultiplication: " << multiply(x, y) << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "\nDivision: " << divide(x, y) << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "\nBigger number: " << greaterNumber(x, y) << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "\nSmaller number: " << lesserNumber(x, y) << endl;
        break;
    }
}

float add(float x, float y)
{
    return (x + y);
}
float subtract(float x, float y)
{
    return (x - y);
}
float multiply(float x, float y)
{
    return (x * y);
}
float divide(float x, float y)
{
    return (x / y);
}
float greaterNumber(float x, float y)
{
    if (x > y)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else return y;
}
float lesserNumber(float x, float y)
{
    if (x < y)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else return y;
}
```

Comment: If you need them in `completeOperation` (which you do) they should be passed as parameters.

Comment: What about changing `completeOperation(int z)` to `completeOperation(int z, int x, int y)` and pass variables?

Comment: Please explain what keeps your from extending the prototype to `void completeOperation(float x, float y, int z);` and then use the parameters for what they are made for.

Comment: @vahancho float instead of int...

Comment: Or even better, create a class UserInput and pass an object of that type. When you have to change some parameters all you have to do is modify this object and it's construction.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't believe I missed that. Changing `void completeOperation(int z);` to `void completeOperation(int z, float x, float y);` resolved all issues. This is my first function with 3 parameters. I hope I'll get better in time. I was staring at this code for hours with no avail.